# Django - serialize complex context structure with models and data

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

In django view I want to be able to serialize whole context, that is usually used to send to template (typically by calling `render` and passing `locals`).
I want to experiment with SPA+API and possibilities to go forward with and I'd like to create function, that would serialize `locals` to json and return it as json response.

Now problem is, that locals is typically mix of lists, dists and querysets of models.
I can serialize models using `django.core.serializers` or using django-rest-framework. I can serialize dict with primitive types using `json` library, but I don't know any simple way how to do mix of those.

Ideal would be way to go through `locals` dictionary and replace all found models with their serialized representations and then put it all together, maybe even specify before what serializer (in sense of drf) to use for which model. But I really don't want to reinvent wheel in case it already exists.

Anoher question is - is this even a good idea to try to do this? Return json context as alternative to server side rendering? I am in prototyping stage so I am still thinking of how to move forward and any input in the area is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand to go with DRF

- `ModelSerializer` will return a Json encoded array of model
- `Serializer` with `DictField` will return a Json encoded `dict`
- `Serializer` with `ListField` will return a Json encoded `list`

You can create `Serializer` with field is another `Serializer` for nesting purpose.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#composite-fields

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects

For your' question is this a good idea, i would said :

- If you push data to an external source (not django) it's fine
- If you push data to django template it's a bad idea, you loose a lot of django power :(

Comment: I am aware of this, but this would require for me to create serializer for every view even though I don't see it as necessary. In my mind all I need to do is to provide serializers for models and rest of it (primitive data types + lists/sets/dicts).

Comment: will work, (But you need to provide the good ModelSerializer) but each view will be like flipping a coin. If you want to structure this with API you need to be stricter or you will lost lot of time to debug